# Struggling with a multiple count statement in SQL

Tags: sql

I've been struggling with a multiple count statement.
my table is build like this;

```
person1, person2, relation
peter     ann      coworkers
```

I need to count how many relations peter has under coworker, under lovers . etc etc

I've come up with this;

```
select(
select count(*)
from rel
where person1 = 'peter' and relation = 'coworker'
)as PetersFriends,(
select count(*)
from rel
where person1 = 'peter' and relation = 'lovers'
)
as PetersLovers
;
```

but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you please try to elaborate more and use proper formatting. I'm afraid, that I don't understand your question. Also: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Are you 'peter'? What if you fall in love with a coworker? :)

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. Is it? If so, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
select relation, count(*) as RelationCount
from rel
where person1='peter'
group by relation
```

Comment: I need to know how many of each relations peter, ann and wendy has

Comment: That's not what your question said. Perhaps you can elaborate from what I've provided above?

Answer (score 1):

Your original query seems to want a pivoted result.  If this is the case you would need something like.

```
select person1,
       COUNT(case when relation = 'coworker' then 1 end) AS Friends,
       COUNT(case when relation = 'lovers' then 1 end) AS Lovers
from rel
where person1 IN ('peter','ann','wendy')
GROUP BY person1
```

Comment: @user493417 - You need to give more details than that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
Peter, Ann, Coworker
```

Will also have a corresponding entry:

```
Ann, Peter, Coworker
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
SELECT Person1, Relation, COUNT(1)
FROM Rel
GROUP BY Person1, Relation
```

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
SELECT Person1, Relation, COUNT(1)
FROM Rel
GROUP BY Person1, Relation
UNION 
SELECT Person2, Relation, COUNT(1)
FROM Rel
GROUP BY Person2, Relation
```